# Algorithm for finding number of squares in a given circle

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, pythagorean

Here is my drawing: [CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HDbH.jpg)

I need to write a program, that will find the number of squares(1x1), that we can draw into a circle of given radius.The squares can only by drawn fully and placed like lego blocks- one on another. In some cases, vertexes of squares can lie on the circle.

Examples: for 1- it makes 0, for 2- it gives four, for 3- 16 squares, for 4-32, for 5-52.

I have written something, but it doesn't work fine for 5+ (I mean- radius bigger than 5). Here it goes: [CLICK](http://pastebin.com/knE1z39K). In my code- r is radius of the circle, sum is the sum of all squares and height is the height of triangles I try to "draw" into the circle (using Pythagorean theorem).

Now- any help? Is my algorithm even correct? Should I change something?

Comment: Your example looks incorrect to me. For example look within the blue circle, there are a number of squares (about 1/2 of those occupied by green rectangles) that also fit within the blue circle.

Comment: When you say in, you want the squares to be ENTIRELY in or PARTIALLY in?

Comment: @Cyber I'm preparing more precise drawing
ENTIRELY, whole square must be in the circle

Comment: @Cyber , as you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/vjUZdsc.jpg , only squares numbere from 1 to 4 fit the circle, the rest (5,6,7,8) isn't correct.

Comment: @NWafel Oh okay, so in your original example, the squares are 2x2 grids from your paper. I thought you were using the 1x1 squares from your grid paper, my mistake.

Comment: By the way, here are my less beautiful squares- I made it for myself, but the scheme is almost in 100% correct: http://i.imgur.com/QI1XMj9.jpg

Comment: @Cyber is there any hope (: ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Gauss's Circle Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html) that gives a formula to count integer points inside the circle of given radius. You may use this logic to count squares that lie in the circle.

```
N = 4 * Sum[i=1..R] (Floor(Sqrt((R^2-i^2)))
```

example:

```
R = 3
i=1   n1 = Floor(Sqrt(9-1))~Floor(2.8)=2
i=2   n2 = Floor(Sqrt(9-4))~Floor(2.2)=2
i=3   n2 = Floor(Sqrt(9-9))=0
N=4*(n1+n2+n3)=16
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** off - circle with a radius of 5 fits 60 1x1 squares, not 52. My bet would be someone didn't count the points {[3,4],[3,-4],[4,3],[4,-3],[-4,3],[-4,-3],[-3,4],[-3,-4]} when drawing that on paper and counting by hand, being unsure whether they are right on the circle or just outside of it. They are exactly on the circle.

**Second** - MBo's answer brought me here - I sometimes search StackOverflow for Gauss Circle Problem to see if someone suggested some new, fun algorithm.

**Third** - here's the code:

```
int     allSquares=0,
        squaredRadius=radius*radius,
        sideOfQuarterOfInscribedSquare=(int)(long)(radius/sqrt(2));
for(int x=sideOfQuarterOfInscribedSquare+1;
        x<radius;
        x++){
    allSquares+=(long)sqrt(squaredRadius-x*x);
}
allSquares= allSquares*8+4*sideOfQuarterOfInscribedSquare*sideOfQuarterOfInscribedSquare;
return allSquares;
```

What it does is just count the squares inside one-eighth of the circle, outside an inscribed square. Sorry for my hipster formatting and overly verbose variable names.